# How to copy resources from one executable to other

Tags: c, winapi, resources, icons, exe

Ok my question is a little odd. But here we go.

I am trying to develop an executable file "wrapper" and a console program. The task of the console program is to copy Icons and Version Informations from another exe file to the wrapper file so that both the wrapper file and the exe file looks exactly same. Apart from that the exe file is appended to the wrapper file at the end. So that when the wrapper is executed it can extract and execute the appended exe file.

My question is how do I create the wrapper file so as to accomodate the Icons and Version info from other exe file ? I mean How should my resource file be ?

And next is How to copy Icons and version info. I hv searched and found a few codes and MSDN instructions but everyone of them uses FindResource, LoadResource, etc. But by following this method, I am losing the original contents of the wrapper file. The size of my file reduces from originally 67kb to 14kb and when I open up in notepad, I see lots of contents are gone ...

can anything be done by using SHGetFileInfo() ? This can be used to get HICON from the exe file. but how do I use this HICON to replace the icon resource in the wrapper file  ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Icon from one exe to another Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278108/copy-icon-from-one-exe-to-another-error)

Comment: wht does it matter ??  someone give answer atleast

Comment: Demanding an answer won't help. Ask the same question over and over won't help. I suggest you read the [faq].

Comment: I know. But this question was a little different from the last one. So I thot I would split it into 2 questions ..

Comment: It's the same question. You want to copy resources from one place to another. Doesn't really matter whether they are icons or versions resources.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278108/copy-icon-from-one-exe-to-another-error) is correct.  You definitely don't want to be mucking around with SHGetFileInfo and HICONs.  The type of resource shouldn't matter.

Your wrapper should start with no resources.  This ensures, for example, that any icon you add will be both first and lowest numbered and thus guaranteed to be used as the app icon.

To understand what's happening with your code, use a tool that can view the resources in the resulting exe.  Visual C++ Express can't do this, but the paid versions can.  Alternatively, Google turns up a bunch of free utilities to do this.  [Here's one,](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) I don't know if it's any good.  The page also contains links to some other tools.

Comment: But if I dont keep any resource in the wrapper then how the program going to update the icon data ???

Comment: @S.Swaroop From MSDN: "UpdateResource adds, deletes, or replaces a resource in a portable executable (PE) file."  You add a resource; what's the problem?

Comment: I tried. I removed all resources from my wrapper file. and then I tried to modify the icon. I used the program here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278108/copy-icon-from-one-exe-to-another-error[link] but it hangs and doesnot do anything. But if I add some random icon resource to the exe before using the program, it is possible to change the icon but size problem occurs.

Comment: @S.Swaroop: Your code hangs because of the way the loops are constructed.  If you don't find the icon then you use `continue` to return to the top of the loop, which means you never check if `iLoop` has reached ten, so the loop never terminates if there's no icon.  A more conventional way to write the loop would be `for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)` and exit the loop (using `break`) when you do find the icon.  P.S. If you stepped through your code in a debugger this would be obvious.